# How to read environment variables in liquibase changelog

Tags: kubernetes, openshift, liquibase

i'm executing a sql query in my changeset as follow:

```
<changeSet author="xxxxx" id="1682329977552-1" context="unittest">
<preConditions onFail="CONTINUE">
 <sqlCheck expectedResult="1"> SELECT COUNT(*) FROM pg_roles WHERE rolname='myuser';</sqlCheck>
</preConditions>
    <sqlFile dbms="!h2, oracle, mysql, postgresql"
             encoding="UTF-8"
             endDelimiter="\nGO"
             path="db_grants.sql"
             relativeToChangelogFile="true"
             splitStatements="true"
             stripComments="true"/>
</changeSet>
```

As you can see, `myuser` is hardcoded which is not desirable, i'm looking for a way to read that user from environment variables but was wondering if it's even possible.

I'm also using that user in `db_grants.sql` which grants some accesses to the user:

```
grant select on all tables in schema public to myuser;
grant insert on all tables in schema public to myuser;
grant delete on all tables in schema public to myuser;
grant update on all tables in schema public to myuser;
```

Good to mention that these scripts runs on **openshift** cluster enviroment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As written in [property-substitution](https://docs.liquibase.com/concepts/changelogs/property-substitution.html) you can pass properties to the liquibase command CLI with `-D` prefix (or you can use other method), so something like `-Dproperty-name=somevalue` and then in your changeSet/sql use it as `${property-name}`.

cmd: `liquibase update -Dpguser=myuser`

```xml
<changeSet author="xxxxx" id="1682329977552-1" context="unittest">
<preConditions onFail="CONTINUE">
 <sqlCheck expectedResult="1"> SELECT COUNT(*) FROM pg_roles WHERE rolname='${pguser}';</sqlCheck>
</preConditions>
    <sqlFile dbms="!h2, oracle, mysql, postgresql"
             encoding="UTF-8"
             endDelimiter="\nGO"
             path="db_grants.sql"
             relativeToChangelogFile="true"
             splitStatements="true"
             stripComments="true"/>
</changeSet>
```

```sql
grant select on all tables in schema public to ${pguser};
grant insert on all tables in schema public to ${pguser};
grant delete on all tables in schema public to ${pguser};
grant update on all tables in schema public to ${pguser};
```

Answer (score 0):

From current documentation:

-D=PARAM                   Pass a name/value pair for substitution in the changelog(s)
Pass as -D<property.name>=<property.value>
**[deprecated: set changelog properties in defaults file or environment variables]**

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).